# When exactly is HttpResponse being sent to the client in .net core API middleware pipeline?

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am so confused about when IIS sends back the response, I really want to know how this works under the hood since I am doing response logging and I don't want to corrupt the body.

This is my logging middleware Invoke which is called before the MVC middleware (controllers). Is the response sent IMMEDIATELY after controller returns its Ok method or does it wait for the rest of the middleware? Is there any chance of corrupting the response if I do logging this way?

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    var requestResponseLog = new RequestResponseLog
    {
        RequestTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
        Request = await FormatRequest(context)
    };

    Stream originalBody = context.Response.Body;

    using (MemoryStream newResponseBody = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream())
    {
        context.Response.Body = newResponseBody;

        await _next(context);

        newResponseBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        await newResponseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBody);

        newResponseBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        requestResponseLog.ResponseTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
        requestResponseLog.Response = await FormatResponse(context, newResponseBody);

        _requestResponseHandler(requestResponseLog);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Think of each registered middleware as a step along the path of creating a request. Your invoke method is "your" step on that path. The `await _next(context);` instructs the framework to move onto the next middleware in the pipeline at that point - but - come back after the rest of the middlewares have executed, so that your code can be picked back up again.

So.. With that in mind, lets assume we have 3 middlewares set up. The pipeline works like this:

**[REQUEST COMES IN]**

Middleware-1 => Middleware-2 => Middleware-3

**[THE RESPONSE IS PRODUCED]**

Middleware-3 => Middleware-2 => Middleware-1

**[RESPONSE GOES OUT TO CALLER]**

Lets say you added `await _next(context)` into Middleware2's Invoke method. When the code reaches that point, it skips onto the next middleware in the pipeline, but it knows to stop there when it comes back through with the response. So you can intercept it again.

If you are logging a request, your custom code would go before that `await _next(context)` call. If you are logging a response, it would come after that call.

*Note: Additionally, middleware ordering is determined by the order they are registered in your Startup class.*

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you for your reply, I understand, however: some people have told me that response goes out to the caller **immediately after** the response has been written to.

Comment: They could be both correct, and wrong. It depends on what you plan to do with the request. **If** you want to change the response sent back to the client, thats a slightly different issue. Since, trying to edit the response once its created will cause problems.